# Cannot delete view-private file

Tags: clearcase

In a dynamic ClearCase view on Windows 7, I've got a file with size 0 and name `myproject.prj.$$$`. I cannot open, delete, rename or modify that file. I'd prefer to delete the file, but when trying to delete it:

- Windows Explorer shows the error message “Invalid MS-DOS function”.
- `cmd.exe`’s `del`: “Incorrect function”.
- ClearCase Explorer simply does nothing.

I've created a file with the same name at a different location, and was able to edit and delete that file without any issues - so I guess the file name is not the issue. The file first showed up after the computer had crashed. I'd prefer not to delete and recreate the view.

What can I do to delete this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks similar to "[Delete of view private file fails with error: Cannot find the specified file](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21150147)":

#### Cause

> The view-private file has been moved or deleted from the view storage within the .s directory.
>
> The view database is still aware of the file and is out of sync with the source container.
>
> Note: The most common reason of this occurrence is due to Virus Scanning. The Virus Scanner is configured to either move a file suspected of a virus to quarantine or is configured to delete the file.

#### Solution 1

> Remove and recreate the view.

#### Solution 2

> If removal of the view is not an option, then synchronize the view database and the source container

The Example below is quite complete, but the [OP Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1826253/martin) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18377131/cannot-delete-view-private-file/18377724#comment26989029_18377724):

> It was not necessary to run the commands:
> The **mvfs log already contained the name of the missing file several times**.
> **After creating an empty file at the "view storage container path", the file in the view could be deleted**.

---

#### Example

The view storage container `800011174be29f22Paul.txt` of the file `Paul.txt` was deleted.

```
M:\niewandt_view5\rn-robin>mvfsstorage Paul.txt
C:\ccstg_c\views\niewandt_view5.vws\.s\00007\800011174be29f22Paul.txt
```

This is the expected result although the file is not there anymore.

Now we flush the mvfs cache:

```
M:\niewandt_view5\rn-robin>mvfscache -f mnode
```

And run the **`mvfsstorage`** command again:

```
M:\niewandt_view5\rn-robin>mvfsstorage Paul.txt
mvfsstorage: Error: Paul.txt - can't fetch cleartext
```

Now we have a problem to identify which storage container is missing.

Trying to open the file gives:

```
---------------------------
Editor
---------------------------
Invalid Function.
---------------------------
OK  
---------------------------
```

If we try to delete the file, it is reporting:

```
---------------------------
Error deleting file or folder
---------------------------

Paul can not be deleted: Invalid MS-DOS function.
---------------------------
OK  
---------------------------
```

To find the view storage container path for that file you need to look in the **mvfs** log.

The mvfs log is showing:

```
{89 pid/tid 139400000cf0/883b7838eb6b63d0} cleartext lookup view=niewandt_view5 vob=\rn-robin dbid=0x80001117 - No such file or directory

{90 pid/tid 139400000cf0/883b7838eb6b63d0} cleartext pname= \Device\HarddiskVolume1\ccstg_c\views\niewandt_view5.vws\.s\00007\800011174be29f22Paul.txt
```

The "\Device\HarddiskVolume1" location can be found on the view properties 'advanced' tab, "Host path" in ClearCase Explorer

Comment: It was not necessary to run the commands - the mvfs log already contained the name of the missing file several times. After creating an empty file at the "view storage container path", the file in the view could be deleted.

Comment: @Martin Excellent. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem recently in windows environment.

*

> (Caution : proceed if you are okay to delete local view-private
>   file which is corrupted and no data of that file can be retrieved)

*

My case was similar to above and was getting the following errors -

```
 1. Windows Explorer shows the error message “Invalid MS-DOS function”.
 2. cmd.exe’s del: “Incorrect function”.
```

I found mvfs log path by typing `mvfslog` in command prompt and that would output following details

```
Log priority:   error
irpops mask:    0x00000000
vops mask:      0x00000000
vfsops mask:    0x00000000
xops mask:      0x00000000
traps mask:     0x00000000
Kernel logfile: "C:\mvfslogs\20191205.log"
```

Now  open the log file from above path

```
"C:\mvfslogs\20191205.log"
```

So if you have got incorrect function recently, then that would be the last data logged as error in above log file.

Opening the log file and observe at the end of file, it reads something similar to below-

```
line #(last-1) - mvfs: Error: ....da..da..da...da... - No such file or directory
line #(last) - mvfs: Error: ....da...da...da...da... \your_container_location\..da..\..da..\..da..your_view_name.vws\.s\00037\800001765bf06476cc3080a
```

So that last word in above path`(800001765bf06476cc3080a)` is you actual file reference of your file in your_container_location. (Some times it might read as 800001765bf06476cc3080ayour_file_name.extension).

So now what is happening is

> it is looking for your file reference 800001765bf06476cc3080a in
>   your_container_location path
>   (\your_container_location..da....da....da..your_view_name.vws.s\00037)
>   but it is not found(As data is not synchronized between your local
>   view and your_container_location).

So now all is required is

```
Step 1-to create a file named as 800001765bf06476cc3080a (as per your file name) in \your_container_location\..da..\..da..\..da..your_view_name.vws\.s\00037

Step 2-refresh your local view.

Step 3-Delete the file.
```

Now that the file should be able to delete permanently. And you can reuse your view.